Counting instances of strings in a corpus and showing the results in a spreadsheet
I have a large corpus of words in plain text.  I want to count all permutations of letter-digraphs within it, e.g. from ab|ba, ac|ca, ad|da... to xy|yx, xz|zx, yz|zy – and display those in a spreadsheet, somewhat like this:
ab 1821 | ba 1334
ac 2745 | ca 3323
...etc.
To give you an idea of my current position, I'm using the "Find"/ "Count" tool in a text editor to count each string and then typing each result into a spreadsheet (Notepad++ & MS Works 9.0, respectively – just in case someone asks).  You may surmise that I'm not a programmer.
Might anyone out there have any suggestions for a more efficient method to compile a spreadsheet, table, CSV, or tabbed plaintext file displaying the frequencies of various strings in a text containing around 180,000 words/ 1 mn characters?
